# How to generate Username auto suggestion like Gmail, Yahoo while Registration

Tags: jquery, gmail, yahoo, autosuggest

I want to implement Username auto suggestion while Registration like Gamil or Yahoo is providing. How can i do that.

Thank You

**Updated**

**Gmail/Yahoo AutoSuggestion**

Gmail is suggesting a username by generating a Random String depending upon the **First name** and **Lastname** by **adding some random characters** to it.

```
ex: firstname: john
    lastname: smith

    Autosuggested Name: johnsmith198, john.34smith, smith45.john etc..
```

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with the way Gmail and Yahoo do this can you describe it?

Comment: @Michael : Thank You Question Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way THEY do it is by considering the FIRST NAME and LAST NAME that a user enters, also sometimes the birthdate etc.
After considering the FN and LN their code searches closest UNUSED username.
Say like FN.LN, LN.FN, FNLNbirthdate or FNRandomnumber.

Obviously you'll have to CODE or copy code from somewhere as to what exactly your Application would suggest the username as.

If any problems still i would be glad to help :)

Comment: Thank You. This is correct but how to check the availability of auto_suggested username in the database. While using Ajax where should we generate a random username, at client side or server side.

Comment: I would say server side as you could send a whole group of possibilities back to the client all at once knowing they are unused.  If your client side makes some random usernames there is a possibility that they would already be taken, which would mean the server would send back a "nope" on some of them causing you to end up with fewer suggestions.  Or if not fewer suggestions, more traffic back and forth with the client asking if the newest one it came up with is already used until it finds enough that are not used.

Comment: @wibbe01: Thank You. you are correct it is better to generate a random username at server-side

Comment: Obviously, server side is BEST option, client side generation would include passing the generated USERNAME back to server for check and then a YES/NO acknowledgment back to client, thus consuming unnecessary bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it would be to ajax the suggestions from the server, sending firstname and lastname as the parameters. The server would generate the random usernames and check they dont exist.

Something you would have to consider is two concurrent users signing up at the same time. You would therefore probably need to 'reserve' the generated usernames so that two users cannot receive the same suggestions.

Comment: Second point is good one. Can u suggest me how to reserve the username at server-side.

Comment: You need to be placing all reserved names in a single globally accessible place such as the application cache, static variable or even the database if you wish (not sure which server side language you are using). When the user submits their chosen username, you also submit the suggestions back to the server and then remove the suggestions from the reservation list. This way unused suggestions are freed up.